# In POSIX sh, string replacement is undefined. while trying to do PASS2="${PASS//[${special_chars}]/}"

Tags: posix, shellcheck

My Code is

```
special_chars='[=!=][=@=][=#=][=$=][=%=][=&=]'
PASS="e@0cc3auZeeSio&G"

PASS2="${PASS//[${special_chars}]/}"
```

I want PASS2 to have all the characters in PASS - special characters.
This works fine, but there is shell check error on this.

```
PASS2="${PASS//[${special_chars}]/}"
             ^-- SC2039: In POSIX sh, string replacement is undefined.
```

I tried doing

```
PASS2=$(printf '%s' "$PASS2" | PASS//["${special_chars}"]/)
```

And

```
PASS2=$(printf '%s' "$PASS" | PASS//["${special_chars}"]/)
```

These does not work functionally.

Comment: Shellcheck is trying to tell you that the `//` construct in parameter expansion is not valid POSIX (it's a bashism). It is also not clear, what the special_chars shall do. Please tell us what PASS2 should be after the transformation. Do you want each of the characters !@$%& removed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This script passes shellcheck:

```
#!/bin/sh

special='!@#$%&'
PASS="e@0cc3auZeeSio&G"
PASS2=$(printf %s "$PASS" | tr -d "$special")
echo "$PASS2"
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @Jens

Comment: I used   PASS2=$(echo "$PASS" | sed 's/[!@#$&%]//g')

Comment: @SashankSekharSingh Wonderful. Yes, sed can also perform the character removal. The next step on Stackoverflow is to "accept" and/or upvote the answer that helped you most by clicking the check mark and/or the upward facing triangle above the vote count.